# Looking for an ISO creator

Tags: iso, unicode

I'm looking for a ISO image creator, already tried `isomaster`, but it doesn't work with unicode chars, it just take it as bad chars, so what other tool can I use?

I don't need booting, just archive them. (Please don't tell me to use tar or whatever, I'm doing so for reasons)

Comment: Have you tried `mkisofs`?

Comment: @Karlson same problem, all non-ascii characters are converted to underscore, and I already specified the right encoding (utf8)

Comment: @warl0ck: did you enable any kind of *extension* to ISO9660? The standard does not allow much more than A-Z and underscores, which is probably why you are getting what you are getting. You probably want to enable Rock Ridge and possibly Joliet, with the `-R` (or `-r`) and `-J` options to `mkisofs`. `mkisofs` will, by default, create a plain ISO9660 image, which is the *standard* data CD format. Most of the CDs you see out there with long file names, unicode in file names and file permissions have either Joliet or RR extensions.

Comment: Also, look into the tool you were using for options that enable these extensions, maybe it supports Joliet and RR and you just didn't know what to look for (btw, Joliet is the Microsoft extension, RR is the UNIX one).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#File_and_directory_name_restrictions

Comment: @njsg -R worked, great

Comment: Nice! Be sure to use -J too if you ever plan to be able to get the proper file names under Microsoft operating systems. OTOH, -R (Rock Ridge) should be fine if you only want to read it under UNIX-like systems (-r will just use different permissions for Rock Ridge, which may be more adequate for readonly media, see the mkisofs manpage).

Comment: @njsg: Your comments should be posted as an answer?

Comment: @SabreWolfy: now that the issue is clearer, I tried to reword what I said in the form of an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ISO9660 standard [does not allow names with other than A-Z, numbers and underscores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#File_and_directory_name_restrictions). No matter which tool you use, if it just creates a plain ISO9660 filesystem, it will likely convert all filenames to respect these restrictions, and possibly even to fit into 8.3 filenames.

Support for other characters in filenames, as well as longer filenames and other filesystem features not found in ISO9660 is usually achieved by using extensions to the standard: in the UNIX world, there is [Rock Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge). Microsoft has [Joliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_%28file_system%29). Enabling one of those will likely give you what you want (I'm not sure about Joliet, but Rock Ridge has always worked with unicode filenames, even if I don't know for sure how are the names encoded).

In `mkisofs`, for example, you use `-R` to enable the Rock Ridge extensions (`-r` for slightly different defaults) and `-J` to enable Joliet. Look for similar options in `isomaster`. You can do well with Rock Ridge. Whether you want to enable Joliet or not depends on whether you plan to read the image under Microsoft OSes. (You can have both at the same time.)